# Filter rows in nested Association / Dataset using Select

Tags: dataset, filtering, associations

The `Dataset` I am working with has the following nested structure.

```
assoc = 
    <|"a" -> <|"k" -> 1, "l" -> <||>|>,
      "b" -> <|"k" -> 2, "l" -> <|"x" -> <|"p" -> 7, "q" -> 8|>|>|>,
      "c" -> <|"k" -> 3, "l" -> <|"y" -> <|"p" -> 9, "q" -> 10|>, "z" -> <|"p" -> 11, "q" -> 12|>|>|>|>;

dataset = Dataset@assoc
```

I would like to filter out rows with some criteria on `p` or `q` while preserving the rest of the rows, columns and structure.

The following example does not preserve the structure, the `k` and `l` keys are missing.

```
dataset[All, "l", Select[#["p"] == 7 || #["p"] == 9 &]]
```

I tried this but it produces all empty rows

```
dataset[All, Select[#["l", "p"] == 7 || #["l", "p"] == 9 &]]
```

Desired result is the following `Association` / `Dataset`

```
assoc2 = 
    <|"a" -> <|"k" -> 1, "l" -> <||>|>,
      "b" -> <|"k" -> 2, "l" -> <|"x" -> <|"p" -> 7, "q" -> 8|>|>|>,
      "c" -> <|"k" -> 3, "l" -> <|"y" -> <|"p" -> 9, "q" -> 10|>|>|>|>;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the following syntax to do what you want:

```
new = dataset[All,{"l"->Select[#["p"]==7||#["p"]==9&]}]
```

[image]

And the normal form of the output:

```
Normal @ new
```

> <|"a" -> <|"k" -> 1, "l" -> <||>|>, 
>    "b" -> <|"k" -> 2, "l" -> <|"x" -> <|"p" -> 7, "q" -> 8|>|>|>, 
>    "c" -> <|"k" -> 3, "l" -> <|"y" -> <|"p" -> 9, "q" -> 10|>|>|>|>

Comment: Thanks! I did not think of using a rule to change the values associated with the `l` key. Based on my very limited understanding of `Association` internals, all of the values are not copied, just the changes. So this should perform well in terms of memory and cpu even for large datasets.