# Using Select on aggregate properties in a hierarchical dataset (association of associations)

Tags: filtering, dataset

I have a hierarchical dataset, called finalData, like this, with 31 entries per 'outer' association.
[image]

What I want to do is select the outer associations (let's call them 'chunks') based on calculated properties of the chunk. So, for example, I might want to keep all chunks in which the minimum #Interval value is >=900. If this was a nested list, and given that Interval is the 9th column in each subarray, I would do

```
Select[finalData,Min[#[[All,9]]]>=900&]
```

Simple! But can this be done within the Dataset paradigm, using a query based on keys? FYI I ca think of plenty of 'hybrid' methods in which one does the test calculation first using something like

```
finalData2[All, Min[#] >= 900 &, "Distance"]
```

and uses the Values[Normal[]] version of this to Pick from the Dataset, but this seems inelegant. Can it be done using a single query?

([This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183418/filter-rows-in-nested-association-dataset-using-select) is the closest but wants to filter the rows within the 'chunks', rather than the chunks themselves.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}][GroupBy["class"]]
```

[image]

Since the minimal age is 1 for all classes, let's take those where the max is less than 80:

```
titanic[All, Max, "age"]
```

[image]

```
titanic[Select[Query[Max /* LessThan[80], "age"]]]
```

[image]

```
titanic[Select[Max@#[[All, "age"]] < 80 &]]
(* same output *)
```

The second example is quite straightforward, it's essentially equivalent to your example. The first one does essentially the same, but in a more dataset-like way (although one can argue whether it's actually any nicer). It works by using a subquery to select the chucks. To illustrate, consider the following partial examples:

```
titanic[All, Max, "age"]

titanic[All, Max /* LessThan[80], "age"]

titanic[All, Query[Max /* LessThan[80], "age"]]

titanic[Select[Query[Max /* LessThan[80], "age"]]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The second example generalizes easily to multiple tests on different keys, e.g., titanic[Select[
  Max[#[[All, "age"]]] < 80 && 
    Count[#[[All, "sex"]], "female"] > 200 &]]    I can't seem to find a way to do that using the subquery format, but it's not a big deal, the other way works!